# Why does voting a post during FP/LA review audit immediately complete the test?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, voting

First of all, we don't know which post is taking a review audit or test. But while the review audit designed, voting the post up or down in first posts and late answers review immediately completes the test and gives us the result.

While we have the ability to take back the vote within 5 minutes and also there is an option "**I'm done**", then why is the test concluded immediately on *just voting*?
Shouldn't it complete when the user finally submits the review?

There is also a possibility that the user fat-fingered the vote-button.
Or that he might want to edit or comment after voting.

What is the reason behind this design of audits?

Comment: You post is valid as far as discussion is concerned. However don't be afraid of downvotes, they dont cost you anything here on Meta. There could be various reasons for a downvote, such as people may not agree with your post, or you may have posted a question without searching the site (already have duplicate posts available), etc.

Comment: Thanks @Aziz i really afraid of downvotes on both SO and meta even when my post was not low quality

Comment: per [your reviews history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3789686/gopal-singh-sirvi?tab=activity&sort=reviews), you seem to be talking about audits in First Posts review - correct?

Comment: yes first post review and late answers review.

Answer (score 6):

The reason voting immediately finishes an audit in the FP/LA queues is simple:

You gave an **unambiguous signal** what should happen with the post, and there's no use wasting your time and attention on doing dozens of additional things which *will just be discarded*.

And if you occassionally mis-vote and immediately correct that, the few review-audits where you did that shouldn't be too significant, in perspective.
Also, mocking up more of the review would be a more than significant and largely useless investment.

Comment: All well and fine, except that in the normal flow, a vote does not end the sequence of events. So I am at liberty to vote as many times as I like before skipping the normal review. Is a vote really then an "**unambiguous signal**"?

Comment: The point of Richard Le Mesurier should be explained...